# Programatically check if a user is a Global Admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, multi-tenancy

I do have a client context `ClientContext context` and current user:

```
var currentUser = context.Web.CurrentUser;

context.Load(currentUser);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I can also use rest API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using **Graph API** rest request:

```
https://graph.windows.net/me/memberOf?api-version=1.6
```

Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

Answer (score 0):

I use this for SharePoint Online:

```
_clientContext.Load(_clientContext.Site, s => s.Url);
_clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
var tenantUrl = $"https://{new Uri(_clientContext.Url).Host.Replace(".sharepoint.com", "-admin.sharepoint.com")}";
var tenantCtx = new ClientContext(tenantUrl);
tenantCtx.Credentials = _clientContext.Credentials;
var tenant = new Tenant(tenantCtx);
var props = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(_clientContext.Site.Url, false);
tenant.Context.Load(props);
tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery(); // will throw 401 exception here, if current user is not tenant admin
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (clientcontext.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin) 
{
   Your Code
}
```

Comment: this returns if a user is a *site admin*. user can be or not be a site admin when he is a global admin.

Comment: I am not sure about how to do it with CSOM but why not try with PowerShell? You will get the list of users who are Global Admins http://office365support.ca/list-and-export-the-admin-roles-assigned-to-users-in-office-365-with-powershell/

Comment: I'm developing an application where Global Admin has admin features so i need to check this in runtime.

Comment: sometimes this code Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin  fails in onpremises.i have tested multiple times within a visual web part, event receivers for checking a user is  belonging to  siteadmin or not. but it returns  incorrect data.